# Check constraint doesn't work in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I have a simple example below

```
begin tran

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Filters]
(
    [Id]                    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [FCode]                 varchar(30) null,
    [FVersion]              varbinary(892) null,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Filter] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id]),

    CONSTRAINT [CK_Filters_FCode_FVersion]  
        CHECK (([FCode] IS NULL AND [FVersion] IS NULL) 
               OR (LEN([FCode]) > 0 AND DATALENGTH([FVersion]) > 0)), 
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Filters] (FCode, FVersion)
VALUES  (NULL, NULL),
        (NULL, 0x6BE348),
        ('ASD', NULL),
        ('ASD', 0x6BE348)

SELECT
    IIF(([FCode] IS NULL AND [FVersion] IS NULL) 
         OR (LEN([FCode]) > 0 AND DATALENGTH([FVersion]) > 0) , 1, 0) AS [check], *
FROM
    [dbo].[filters]

rollback
```

I expect that the 2nd and 3rd insert statements will cause the constraint violation. However server allows them.

In use the select statement to see that the value of the constraint check is violated for 2nd and 3rd rows. See the result

```
check   Id  FCode   FVersion
------------------------------
1       1   NULL    NULL
0       2   NULL    0x6BE348
0       3   ASD     NULL
1       4   ASD     0x6BE348
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Check constraints only fail when the value is definitively `false`.

The expressions that you expect to violate the constraint evaluate to `UNKNOWN`.

You can see this with

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN( ( [FCode] IS NULL
                 AND [FVersion] IS NULL )
                OR ( LEN([FCode]) > 0
                     AND DATALENGTH([FVersion]) > 0 ) ) THEN 'True'
         WHEN NOT ( ( [FCode] IS NULL
                      AND [FVersion] IS NULL )
                     OR ( LEN([FCode]) > 0
                          AND DATALENGTH([FVersion]) > 0 ) ) THEN 'False'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
       END                    AS [check],
       LEN([FCode])           AS LenFCode,
       DATALENGTH([FVersion]) AS DataLengthFVersion,
       *
FROM   [dbo].[filters]
```

Which returns

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+----+-------+----------+
|  check  | LenFCode | DataLengthFVersion | Id | FCode | FVersion |
+---------+----------+--------------------+----+-------+----------+
| True    | NULL     | NULL               |  1 | NULL  | NULL     |
| Unknown | NULL     | 3                  |  2 | NULL  | 0x6BE348 |
| Unknown | 3        | NULL               |  3 | ASD   | NULL     |
| True    | 3        | 3                  |  4 | ASD   | 0x6BE348 |
+---------+----------+--------------------+----+-------+----------+
```

The reason they are `UNKNOWN` is because `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` both return `NULL` when passed `NULL`

Comment: Thank you! That was the reason.

Comment: Excellent example

Answer (score 0):

[Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560730/435559)'s answer already included the reason behind why SQL server is allowing specified values without violating check constraint.

You can modify your check constraint to following to make it work. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5637)

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_Filters_FCode_FVersion]  
        CHECK (([FCode] IS NULL AND [FVersion] IS NULL) 
               OR (LEN(ISNULL([FCode],'')) > 0 
                   AND ISNULL(DATALENGTH([FVersion]),-1) > 0))
```